# Which version of node is used in BigQuery UDF?

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery

I'm working on a javascript UDF that I want to use to do a dbscan in BigQuery. It is looking good so far, but I do get different results when running the code in BigQuery compared to testing it locally through node. To figure out what's going on I need to know the version of node that BigQuery is using, or is it another javascript runtime that is in use?

Comment: It would help a lot if you shared code and results.

Comment: I figured out the issue, it was not about different versions of node, it was because INT64 is passed as strings because of reasons. Why do you need my code and result to tell which version of node that is running @FelipeHoffa? I think that information should be publicly available since then you can configure the tooling to target the version locally when developing a script.

Comment: interestingly enough - BigQuery doesn't use node - so while the direct question is not answerable ("I need to know the version of node that BigQuery is using"), having your code could help us answer the underlying one "I do get different results when running the code in BigQuery compared to testing it locally".

Comment: I figured out the issue myself @FelipeHoffa, and it was a user error on my end. I had forgot that int64 was interpreted as string runtime when passed to an udf. If node is not used it would be interesting to know which version is used if possible.

Comment: hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52825129/can-i-use-js-bigint-in-a-bigquery-udf/52825130#52825130

Comment: Thanks, that does help :)